# Is this proof for $\vdash p\vee\neg p$ correct and what other proof would you suggest?

Tags: proof-verification, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

1. $\;\bullet\;\neg(p\vee\neg p)$ --- assumption
2. $\;\bullet\;\neg p\wedge\neg\neg p$ --- DM 1 (De Morgan Law)
3. $\;\bullet\;\neg p$ --- $\wedge$ elim 2
4. $\;\bullet\;\neg\neg p$ --- $\wedge$ elim 2
5. $\;\bullet\;\bot$ --- $\bot$ intro 3,4
6. $\;p\vee\neg p$ --- RAA 1 - 5

Comment: which rule is given, RAA or DNE?

Comment: I've included proofs [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2436580/328173)

Comment: actually I'm learning it from internet and not a specific book, can't quite understand what you mean but RAA is a derived rule and standing for Reductio Ad Absurdum and has a separate proof

Comment: I mean, what rules can you use? Because $\vdash p \lor \neg p$ is just LEM and is a given in many classical systems.

Comment: Oh I see law of excluded middle, and you can't use DNE because in its proof LEM is used(in proofwiki)!

Comment: LEM and DNE and RAA are equivalent in the sense that you can prove one from the other, assuming intuitionistic logic, as demonstrated in my link.

Comment: So please clarify, whether you are seeking a proof of LEM from RAA or from DNE.

Comment: hmmm... the one from RAA please :D

Comment: Note that the rule you used in your question is actually DNE, not RAA.

Comment: Isn't DNE standing for double negation elimination?! if so how have I used it?!

Comment: From 1-5 and $\neg$-intro you will obtain $6. \neg \neg (p \lor \neg p)$, and then you can use DNE to obtain $7. p \lor \neg p$.

Comment: Double negation elimination means $\lnot \lnot p \equiv p$.  And so $(\lnot p\land p) \to \bot)$.........

Comment: Well that's RAA!

Comment: Indeed, Pooria!

Comment: RAA is $\neg \varphi \to \psi, \neg \varphi \to \neg \psi \vdash \varphi$ in my nomenclature @amWhy

Comment: http://imps.mcmaster.ca/courses/CAS-701-02/contributions/nat-deduction.pdf please take a look here for RAA

Comment: Hmm, I wonder what the name of what I just said is.

Comment: @Pooria Ugh. In that link you posted $\neg A$ is *defined* as $A \rightarrow \bot$ ... well, you get a perfectly complete proof system that way, but not a very user-friendly. May I recommend you look for some system that has $\neg$ as a basic connective? I think that'll avoid some of your confusions.

Comment: See also the post [prove that $\vdash p \lor \lnot p$ is true using natural deduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439291/prove-that-vdash-p-lor-lnot-p-is-true-using-natural-deduction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is alright apart from the fact that you used DM1, which although is true in intuitionistic logic, is usually not a given (it is also not given in the [natural deduction system you linked](http://imps.mcmaster.ca/courses/CAS-701-02/contributions/nat-deduction.pdf)).

This is because DM2 is invalid in intuitionistic logic.

So, here's a proof using RAA but not DM1:

```
  01. ¬[p∨¬p]   assumption
    02. p       assumption
    03. p∨¬p    ∨intro 02
    04. ⊥       contradiction 03 01
  05. ¬p        ¬intro 02-04
  06. p∨¬p      ∨intro 05
  07. ⊥         contradiction 06 01
08. p∨¬p        RAA 01-07
```